# How can I make the zoning colours more distinct?

Tags: cities-skylines

I have installed Cities Skylines on my HP Envy m6 laptop with Ubuntu 14 installed. I also have the laptop plugged into a 27 inch monitor.

The game appears to run without any issues, except for an exception when closing down. However, when I try to mark any of the first zones the zone colours are incredibly faint. So much so, that when I first tried to zone an area I kept clicking and dragging thinking that nothing was happening.

It took some time before I realised the zones were in fact being marked, it's just hard to see.

Is there a way to increase the visibility of the zone colours?

Perhaps a mod that does this?

Comment: Do you have any known vision problem or is it possibly just some horrible contrast on your monitor? Have you tried using some of the color profile overwrites in the options menu (which also changes lighting)?

Comment: No known vision problems, I get my eyes checked annually, last time being November and they were fine.

The monitor works nicely with other games. I suspect it's a combination of the monitor, the output from the laptop VGA port, and possibly the Linux drivers. 

I am wondering if anyone else has come across this. But if not maybe there's a way to strengthen the zone colours.

Comment: Check this [monitor calibration site](http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-calibrate-your-monitor/2/) in case you would need to adjust your monitor. Also, to you have a dedicated card in that laptop?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

This probably isn't the case for you (and isn't for me), but it wouldn't surprise me if people with red/green [colour blindness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness) couldn't distinguish the colour used for residential zones from the colour for industrial zones, and those with blue/yellow colour blindness having difficulty distinguishing commercial zones from residential zones.  Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any options for colour blind people, but one thing you can try is forcing the colour palette to one of the climates (Temperate, Boreal, or Tropical) in the options.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I find Cities Skylines' colors to be more vibrant than the average (3D) game.

I'd look into your monitor's settings, as I would expect this to be a direct display issue.

That being said, the green zoning for residential zones might sometimes be hard to see if you're building on grassy land. Especially if your monitor doesn't have a very wide range of colors, since the shades of green are already close to one another.